# PHP echo within an echo

Tags: php, echo

I have a php script to echo out a set number of posts per page:

```
<div class="posts">
    <?php echo $post[1]; ?>
    <?php echo $post[2]; ?>
    <?php echo $post[3]; ?>
    <?php echo $post[4]; ?>
</div>
```

This works fine, but I'd like to hold the data in a seperate php section, and then echo it out using a simple statement. So for this I created:

```
$posts = "".$post_single[1];$post_single[2];$post_single[3];$post_single[4];."";  // Error On This Line

<div class="posts">
    <?php echo $posts; ?>
</div>
```

Whe I run this, I get the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in ...`

Any ideas how I can fix this to echo out the `$posts` line correctly?

Comment: This is a error code, maybe closing ?> or <?php.. show the entire error please. OH i see... here is the error $post_single[4];.""; ... closing ; early

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`;` indicates the end of a statement. `.` concatenates two strings. You are confusing the two.

```
$posts = "" . $post_single[1] . $post_single[2] . $post_single[3] . $post_single[4] . "";
```

---

That said, concatenating empty strings on to the start and end is pointless. So don't do that.

```
$posts = $post_single[1] . $post_single[2] . $post_single[3] . $post_single[4];
```

---

And that said, concatenating everything in an array by explicit index is very long-winded. There is a function designed for that.

```
$posts = implode($post_single);
```

Note this will also include `$post_single[0]` which you were ignoring.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works great, although I can't use the `implode` version as `$single_post[0]` is used further up in the page, and is therefore not needed in the `$posts` string

Answer (score 1):

you're not echoing correctly, you need to concat each variable, for example:

```
$stringOne = 'hello';
$stringTwo = 'world';

echo $stringOne. ' ' .$stringTwo; # this will output hello world;
```

so in your case:

```
$posts = "".$post_single[1];$post_single[2];$post_single[3];$post_single[4];."";
```

should be

```
$posts = "".$post_single[1]. $post_single[2]. $post_single[3]. $post_single[4] ."";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$posts = "".$post_single[1]."".$post_single[2]."".$post_single[3]."".$post_single[4];

<div class="posts">
    <?php echo $posts; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a loop ? Something like this

```
<div class="posts">
    <?php 
       foreach ($posts as $post) {
         echo $post;
       }
     ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of this:

```
$posts = "".$post_single[1];$post_single[2];$post_single[3];$post_single[4];."";
```

try this:

```
$posts = $post_single[1].$post_single[2].$post_single[3].$post_single[4];
```

or this:

```
$posts = "{$post_single[1]}{$post_single[2]}{$post_single[3]}{$post_single[4]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
$posts = "".$post_single[1];$post_single[2];$post_single[3];$post_single[4];."";
```

try this :

```
$posts = "".$post_single[1] . $post_single[2] . $post_single[3] . $post_single[4]."";
```

use **.** operator to concat the variables.

```
<div class="posts">
    <?php echo $posts; ?>
</div>
```